# spyder not producing graphs in plots pane

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, subplot

I do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=3)
```

and I get a 3x3 arrangement of empty graphs in the spyder plots pane.

Then I do

```
ax=axes[0][0]
ax.plot(x,y,marker='o')
```

All 9 graphs remain completely empty and unchanged.  I get no error messages of any kind.  matplotlib seems to think it is doing what it is supposed to do.  If I do a simple plot, though,

```
ax.plot(x,y,marker='o')
```

I do get a new plot showing the graph I expect.

Anyone know what the problem might be plotting to a subplot in a grid?  I have tried toggling inline plotting with no effect.  I thought the graphics backend might be a problem, but I don't know enough about it to know how to reset it or what to set it to.

I am running spyder 4.1.4 on a Windows 10 system.

UPDATE:  By finding the right backend, I was able to get plots away from the plots pane and into the old plot window that spyder used in previous versions, and can plot as before w/o trouble.  Still bugs me that I can't use the plots pane.  If anyone has any insight, I would still be happy to receive it.

Comment: Did you find a solution that allows you to use plots pane for subplots?

Comment: @user3731622  The problem mysteriously cleared up the next day.  No idea why.  Hope you weren't hoping for a clearer answer!  :-)